# A cylinder in a zone of stationery dust particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass

A rod of mass $M$ and cross - sectional area $A$ first enters a zone of stationery dust particles of density $ \rho_1 $ and length $ x_1 $ and then yet another zone of dust particles of density $\rho_2$ and length $x_2$. the dust particles stick only on the front end face of the rod. The velocities of the rod at the start of the second zone and at the end of the second zone are $V_1$ and $V_2$. Find the time of the journey of the rod in the second zone.

What I did was that I conserved the momentum from the start of the second zone to some arbitrary distance $x$ in the second zone and wrote velocity as that point as $\frac{dy}{dx} $ and then solved.
$$
\int(M+\rho Ax_1).V_1=\int (M+\rho Ax_1+\rho Ax) \frac{dx}{dt}
$$

Am i doing something wrong

Comment: Note that this site isn't a homework help site, it's a Q&A site based on answering questions about physics *concepts*. As it stands, your question is about mistakes you've made in attempting to solve a problem, which isn't a concept question. Take a few minutes to think about what physics concept you're struggling with, then ask about that.